# Java Socket exception

Tags: java

I am trying to write a simple client server program in Java :-
Running both server and client code on the same machine...but while running getting an error :-

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
        at Requester.run(Requester.java:13)
        at Requester.main(Requester.java:68)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Requester.run(Requester.java:45)
        at Requester.main(Requester.java:68)
```

Can anyone help!

Comment: Can you post your code-snippet,

Comment: Yes, come code would be nice, also please format the stack trace correctly, it's barely readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the port you are trying to connect to open? Is there an active firewall that may block the request?

Comment: @Monojeet: From the machine that will run this code, you could attempt to telnet to the server/port: `telnet [host] [port]` . If that doesn't work, then there is little chance that the Java program will work.

Comment: the port should be open as soon as you successfully start your server. to check if you can connect to that port, use telnet as Adam said: telnet localhost <your port here>